# Blend negative value into framebuffer 0 opengl

Tags: opengl-es, framebuffer, blending

The program renders a bunch of things into an intermediate framebuffer that uses an unsigned normalized texture to store the data. The intermediate framebuffer is blended with the default framebuffer. The pixel shader used to render the intermediate for the blend with framebuffer 0 is the following:

```
#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

out vec4 fragColor;

in vec2 texCoords;

uniform sampler2D textureToDraw;

void main()
{
    vec4 sampleColor = texture(textureToDraw, texCoords);
    fragColor = vec4(sampleColor.rgb * -1.0, sampleColor.a);
}
```

The code for setting up the draw to framebuffer 0 is as follows:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBlendEquationSeparate(GL_FUNC_ADD, GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// Draw the intermediate using the pixel shader above and a quad
```

The rgb components of `fragColor` will be in the range [-1, 0]. The expected result is that the intermediate color is subtracted from the previous framebuffer contents. The actual result is that the color black is blended with correct alpha with framebuffer 0, which indicates that `fragColor` is clamped to [0, 1] somewhere and the negative portion is discarded.

Is there a way to disable clamping of fragment shader outputs to [0, 1]?

I know that there is not a way to render to a signed normalized texture, so maybe there is an OpenGL limitation that prevents this. The alternative that I am thinking of is doing two render passes, one which renders the negative bits to an intermediate and the other that renders the positive ones to another intermediate. At the end, blend positive with `GL_FUNC_ADD` and negative with `GL_FUNC_REVERSE_SUBTRACT`. This is slow and cumbersome to maintain. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to disable clamping of fragment shader outputs to [0, 1]?

Let me quote from section *17.3.6 Blending* of the [OpenGL 4.6 Core Profile Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> If the color buffer is fixed-point, the components of the **source** and destination values and blend factors are each clamped to [0, 1] or [−1, 1] respectively for an unsigned normalized or signed normalized color buffer prior to evaluating the blend equation. **If the color buffer is floating-point, no clamping occurs.** The resulting
>   four values are sent to the next operation.

So you can use one of the `*16F` or `*32F` formats to get rid of the clamping.

> I know that there is not a way to render to a signed normalized texture, so maybe there is an OpenGL limitation that prevents this.

The spec marks the various `_SNORM` as *color-renderable*. However, at the same time, the spec does not mark these formats as *required* to be supported for a render target, so implementations *can* allow you to use such a format, but they don't have to, so yes, you can't relie on that in any way...

Comment: Thank you for these details! Rendering to a floating point texture works as expected and preserves sign. It looks like negative values are still clamped before blend with the default framebuffer though. Is there a way to set the internal format of the default framebuffer to a floating point one as well?

Comment: Format support depends on the operating system, but it's unlikely that a display surface on most devices today would understand floating point (unless you have an HDR panel it doesn't make a lot of sense).

Comment: For OpenGL ES also note that floating point rendering is only mandatory in ES 3.2, so will only work on newer devices. Also note that it's very memory bandwidth heavy (more bits per pixel, don't always get surface compression), so while you *can* do it, it may not be a good idea for overall application efficiency.

Comment: I ended up grouping layers in my scene into composable blocks that were blended together into a floating point intermediate. These are organized in a tree so that the child composable block blends into the parent intermediate. Since OpenGL does not clamp negative values on blends destined for floating point textures, this worked as expected. When rendering to the default frame buffer, negative values are clamped as expected, and at this point this is ok.